# Recover missing Exchange items

Tags: exchange, exchange-2003

We are a small office with 6 computers, running Exchange 2003 on office server. Each client computer has Mozilla Thunderbird installed with IMAP connection to Exchange Server.

Few days ago we discovered that there are emails missing in some mailboxes (receive period 09-2011 to 12-2011).

I have checked all folders, and deleted items, but the items just disappeared. Interesting fact is that some mailboxes did not experience this same problem. What should be the next step in order to locate and retrieve these items on Exchange?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When everything is recovered from the backup/recovery system into a Recovery Storage Group, Exchange will give you the option (Under "Exchange Tasks" in the context menu of the restored mailbox in the mailstore under the Recovery Storage group) of copying the recovered data into the users mailbox or merge it as mentioned above.

Comment: I have located Exchange backup, but it is emtpy. It seems that backup was not properly configured. Is it possible to check the integrity of Exchange backup or is there a way to find messages in a file format?

Answer (score 2):

Restore the mailboxes from backup.

Comment: Would that override current mailbox items?

Comment: Most backup systems will let you either merge the restored data into the mailbox or export a PST of the mailbox.